# textbox onchange event using jquery causes JScript runtime error: 'Deductions' is undefined

Tags: jquery, onchange

I have a query regarding calling jQuery for textbox onchange event.

in my coding am calling onchange event as

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtTotalDeductions"  Text="0" runat="server" 
                                                        ClientIDMode="Static"     onChange="Deductions();" ></asp:TextBox>
```

and I have two div sections as

```
<div id="Total">1000</div>
```

and

```
<div id="NetTotal">0</div>
```

I need to calculate the "NetTotal" by subtracting the Total - txtTotalDeductions.

and my jQuery for Deductions is

//Calculate deductions.

```
function Deductions() {


      var result = new Object();

      result.total = $("#Total").html();
      result.totalDeductions = $("#txtTotalDeductions").val();

      result.netTotal = result.total - result.totalDeductions;
      $('#NetTotal').html(result.netTotal);
  }
```

and when I run the application the error shows like "Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'Deductions' is undefined", and the error lies here ""

can anyone help me out pls.....thanks in advance

Comment: Where did you defined your java-script function? You need to define it    in globally.

Comment: Have you by any chance defined the function `Deductions` inside domready of jQuery? i.e. inside `$(document).ready({//here })` or inside `$(function(){ //here })`?

Comment: I am a newbie to jQuery, I just defined it in custom.js file in a seperate folder

Answer (score 10, accepted):

remove the OnChange handler

```
function Deductions() {


      var result = new Object();

      result.total = $("#Total").html();
      result.totalDeductions = $("#txtTotalDeductions").val();

      result.netTotal = result.total - result.totalDeductions;
      $('#NetTotal').html(result.netTotal);
  }
```

also wrap the code inside the ready handler and attach a change event handler

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 //attach with the id od deductions
$("#txtTotalDeductions").bind("change",Deductions);

});
```

Comment: thanks john for ur reply, I dont understand what you are saying, you r asking me to remove the onchange="Deductions();" in textbox

Comment: yes remove the inline event and bind the event to the textbox in the document ready handler, inline events are not recommended...can you tell me what is the id generated for the textbox...

Comment: sorry john I still dont understand, can you please tell elaborately.....what I want to do is, when I make some changes in the deductions textbox and leave from it, it should calculate the value in the div(total) - deductions and should display the result in the netamount(div tag)......how I should call the jQuery and where I've to put the ready function...

Comment: @Shanish : Just put the above code (both the snippets) in your `custom.js` file and make sure you attach it to the concerned page. For basics of jQuery, refer to the official jQuery documentation and w3schools at http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp .Also go through the videos at http://learn.appendto.com/lessons

Comment: @Shanish : As far as John's answer is concerned, instead of declaring the `onchange` event in the page itself, john has dynamically bound it to the textbox with `$("#txtTotalDeductions").bind("change",Deductions);` which in short registers a `change` event on `txtTotalDeductions` and calls the `Deducations` function when the event occurs.

Comment: thanks nikhil and john for spending your valuable time for me, I'll go through the links u've given and let you know once I fixed the issue..thanks once again

Comment: @NikhilPatil thnx for giving me a hand here... `:)`

Comment: Hi NikhilPatil and John finally its working fine.. I just tried the coding in my ascx scripting page, by using the blur event....I declared the blur event in my page_load.....its working fine....thanks for ur valuable guidance

Comment: @Shanish glad that helped, you can mark this answer if it helped you `:)`... the tick box that is visible beside the question clicking that will mark this answer as accepted ... `:p`

Comment: @John, sorry john am new to this forum, I dont have enough reputation to mark your solution.

Comment: Glad I could help Shanish, @john :)

Answer (score 3):

Change your jScript to this, this will help :

```
$(function (){
    $('#txtTotalDeductions').change(function (){
      var total = $("#Total").html();
      var totalDeductions = $("#txtTotalDeductions").val();

      var netTotal = total - totalDeductions;
      $('#NetTotal').html(netTotal);

        });       

});
```

you can also use object. i have removed it for my convinience.

edit:

Remove your onchange event from textbox and also remove function deduction.

Comment: Thanks dhaval I can understand your code, I think I've missed some jQuery reference....I'll check it and then let you know.....thanks once again for ur response

Comment: Hi dhaval finally its working.. I just tried the coding in my ascx scripting page, by using the blur event.....its working fine....thanks for ur valuable guidance