# Retrieving already assigned text box value dynamically in javascript

Tags: php, javascript

I have a form in PHP which looks like this:

```
<?php
   $txtVal1 = "value1";
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
 function post_data(){
   alert(document.getElementById("text1").value);
 }
</script>
<form method="post" action="">
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $txtVal1;?>" id="text1"/>
<input type="button" value="Post" onclick="post_data()"/>
</form>
```

My question is whenever I click "Post" button I get an alert message as "value1". This is fine. But now if I change the text box value to something else from the UI I still get the old value. Is there any solution to get the changed value?

Comment: edit: ok u fixed the typo

Comment: @hafichuk: No I dont refresh the webpage. I just input any custom text in the text box and press the Post button and expect to get my changes in the alert box.

Comment: [See This](http://beta.tinyclark.com/stackstuff/sanks.php), running on my server this code runs just as you are describing it should...

Comment: I see nothing wrong with it.

Comment: I ran your code and well the results were as expected. At first, the default value in the text box is 'Value1' and when i pressed the button i got value1 in the alert box . Then later i changed the value of the text form the UI to '1234' , 'hello world' and other values. And well '1234', 'hello world' were all alerted. What is the proble you are having?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. this works. check if your php value is putting value correctly or not

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
 function post_data(){
   alert(document.getElementById("text1").value);

 }
</script>

<form method="post" action="">
<input type="text" id="text1"/>
<input type="button" value="Post" onclick="post_data()"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your page when ever load the first php value assign and after that run all value that is the problem for that. You change to assign value for the above one `$txtVal1 = "value1";`

Comment: No I don't submit the form or refresh the webpage. I just want my changed text to be alerted in the alert box

Comment: Then you need to use onChange event for your input box.

Comment: yes u add a event for onChange() that work this is the site for sample http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp

Comment: Do note it'll call the function every time you add / delete a letter to the input box.

Comment: u see that this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9563204/textbox-onchange-event-using-jquery

Answer (score 0):

```
<pre>
<?php <br/>
   $txtVal1 = "value1";<>
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
 function post_data(){
   alert(document.getElementById("text1").value);
 }

 function test(val){
    document.getElementById("text1").value = val;
 }
</script>
<form method="post" action="">
<input type="text1" value="<?php echo $txtVal1;?>" onChange="test(this.value)" id="text1"/>
<input type="button" value="Post" onclick="post_data()"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this [jQuery fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yG39B/)

It may be overkill but it works. StackOverflow doesn't like links to jsfiddle?

```
$("#submit").click(function(){
    alert($("#text1").val());
});
```

Comment: They don't like it because if\when your fiddle is removed or changed, your link would be worthless