# How to get a string input and store it into a var

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know it's simple and there's probably something wrong with my syntax but I just don't understated it. I'm talking about the following:

```
//declaration of a string
var str_input = "";

//this is supposed to get the new inputs and to store them in str_input
$(document).ready(function(){

   str_input = $('input[name=po]').val();

});

//this is on html side, this should make an input field where the user to type in the needed
<input type"text" name = 'po' id="po" value="asd">
```

That's it, can you help me to sort it out? The problem so far is that str_input is `undefined` regardless of what is written in the input, though, it saves its initial value.

Comment: Try `$('input[name="po"]').val()`

Comment: Since you've got `id="po"` in the element, `$('#po').val()` will work.

Comment: I made it in jsFiddle with your exact code and it worked, did you include the jquery library?

Comment: Actually I'm not sure that it updates the value with the next input correctly. I don't know, there is no way, as far as I see it, this the jquery part to update str_input on change of input, hmmm...

Comment: You may want to add a button or some event to the input so that the "str_input" variable is updated with the new value as another idea here. When are you wanting that "str_input" to have the textbox value and what is supposed to enforce that?

Comment: @KDX2 I don't really understand what you want to do, this code works perfect for me, the str_input get the value of asd

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9563204/textbox-onchange-event-using-jquery would be a way to add an onchange here that may resolve the next part I think.

Answer (score 2):

Your html tag is invalid:

```
<input type"text" name = 'po' id="po" value="asd">
```

Should be:

```
<input type="text" name = 'po' id="po" value="asd">
        // ^ Missing this character (=)
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, Now I understood, you can do 2 things, first, you can create a button than when the user clicks it calls the function to store the value in the variable like this:

```
var str_input = "";

//this is supposed to get the new inputs and to store them in str_input
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#MyButton").click(function(){
str_input = $('input[name=po]').val();
})


});

//this is on html side, this should make an input field where the user to type in the needed
<input type"text" name = 'po' id="po" value="asd">
<input type="button" id="MyButton" value="Click Here" />
```

Or the blur function when the user lose focus of the input text like this:

```
   var str_input = "";

    //this is supposed to get the new inputs and to store them in str_input
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[name=po]').blur(function(){
    str_input = $('input[name=po]').val();
    })


    });

    //this is on html side, this should make an input field where the user to type in the needed
    <input type"text" name = 'po' id="po" value="asd">
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so here is the solution, though it's a little bit in "from Alf to Alf" style. So, yes, the code I've posted in the main post uses correctly the 'by default' value of the input but the problem comes from that nothing is checking for further changes in the input text field. I'm using $(document).ready... which as far as I know runs during the web project is opened and of course enables the use of some jquery methods within it. There is an interesting function called `.change()` which actually put the whole thing up for me. Take a glance at the following:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $('input[type="text"]').change(function(){
            str_input = $('input[name=polynom]').val();;
        });
   str_input = $('input[name=polynom]').val();

});
```

The second, third and fourth line make the magic actually, where the code in the `.change()` method **updates** str_input on each time a change have appeared in the input box field, whereas the `str_input = $('input[name=polynom]').val();` outside of change() takes into account the initial value of the input. That's it... I knew I was forgetting something and yeah...

P.S. Another approach is to use a function and a button (a.k.a. an event-triggered function) which to 'update' the str_input on event. For this way check the post bellow this one.